# In Python, can I use the value of a global variable in a method at the time of it's definition, but not change when that variable is changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, global-variables

It's difficult to describe the behavior that I need, so I'll give an example.  When running the following code, `f()` prints `"eggs"`, but I would like a way to make `f()` print `"spam"`, which is the value of `x` at the time of `f`'s declaration.

```
x = "spam"
def f():
    print(x)
x = "eggs"
f()
```

This doesn't seem very pythonic, but I've given a lot of thought to the problem I'm facing, and have concluded that this solution is the most elegant.  I can give more details about the exact example that requires this solution if that's necessary.

Comment: This sounds like bad programming practice. I guarantee there's a better way.

Comment: You could bind it using a default argument, they're set when the function is defined - `def f(x=x): ...`. But @Tyler is probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then bind `x` to `f` as soon as `f` is defined:

```
x = "spam"
def f(x=x):
    print(x)

x = "eggs"
f()
# spam
```

Probably not a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Moses Koledoye's answer is sufficient, but through experimentation I have found that the following also works in Python 3:

```
from functools import partial
x = "spam"
f = partial(print, x)
x = "eggs"
f()
```

I'm just making note of this because it always helps to have options

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply just call the function before you set x equal to spam, like this:

```
x = 'spam' 
def f():
     print(x)
f()
x = "eggs"
```

The output for that would be 'spam' since you are calling the function before you are setting x equal to "eggs". Hope this helped